# Issues publishing to device shadow using the aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-iot

In a python application that uses the [aws iot device sdk for python v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2) (v1.7.1) I am running into an issue where I cannot update the device shadow.

After starting the program, the `DeviceShadowManager` will attempt to get the latest shadow state and set it locally.
If a `delta` state is present the `DeviceShadowManager` will merge the last `reported` state and `delta` state and publish it.
That works. However, when the manager subscribes for updates, after the initial setup, I am running into an error,
where when the `desired` state changes, the manager cannot update the `reported` state. Here is the error:

```
Exception ignored in: <class 'TypeError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tom/.../lib/python3.9/site-packages/awscrt/mqtt.py", line 506, in callback_wrapper
    callback(topic=topic, payload=payload)
TypeError: callback_wrapper() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'dup', 'qos', and 'retain'
```

I looked at [the source](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-python/blob/e7e8046195d062ebc34e0addc9d6c1b9c17833de/awscrt/mqtt.py#L506), but just do not understand why a `TypeError` is raised,
especially because this exact scenario seems to be handled by the `try` and `except` block or am I getting it all wrong?

The source of the error:

```
 if callback:
    def callback_wrapper(topic, payload, dup, qos, retain):
        try:
            callback(topic=topic, payload=payload, dup=dup, qos=QoS(qos), retain=retain)
        except TypeError:
            # This callback used to have fewer args.
            # Try again, passing only those those args, to cover case where
            # user function failed to take forward-compatibility **kwargs.
            callback(topic=topic, payload=payload) # this is line 506
```

Below you can find my code and the log of the program.

This dataclass represents the shadow:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class DeviceShadow:
    score_threshold: float = 0.6
    minimum_distance: int = 150
```

The shadow is managed by the `DeviceShadowManager`. Most of this is based on the [shadow sample](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/blob/main/samples/shadow.py) from the aforementioned [repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2).

```
from dataclasses import asdict
from queue import Queue
from threading import Lock

from awscrt import mqtt
from awsiot import iotshadow
from awsiot.iotshadow import IotShadowClient

from app.device_shadow.device_shadow import DeviceShadow, from_json as device_shadow_from_json
from app.models import log

SHADOW_VALUE_DEFAULT = DeviceShadow()


class DeviceShadowManager:
    _shadow_client: IotShadowClient
    shadow_value: DeviceShadow = DeviceShadow()

    _lock = Lock()
    _thing_name: str

    def __init__(self, thing_name: str, mqtt_connection: mqtt.Connection):
        self._thing_name = thing_name
        self._shadow_client = iotshadow.IotShadowClient(mqtt_connection)

        update_accepted_subscribed_future, _ = self._shadow_client.subscribe_to_update_shadow_accepted(
            request=iotshadow.UpdateShadowSubscriptionRequest(thing_name=self._thing_name),
            qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
            callback=self.on_update_shadow_accepted  # omitted
        )

        update_rejected_subscribed_future, _ = self._shadow_client.subscribe_to_update_shadow_rejected(
            request=iotshadow.UpdateShadowSubscriptionRequest(thing_name=self._thing_name),
            qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
            callback=self.on_update_shadow_rejected  # omitted
        )

        # Wait for subscriptions to succeed
        update_accepted_subscribed_future.result(60)
        update_rejected_subscribed_future.result(60)

        log.info("Subscribing to Get responses...")
        get_accepted_subscribed_future, _ = self._shadow_client.subscribe_to_get_shadow_accepted(
            request=iotshadow.GetShadowSubscriptionRequest(thing_name=self._thing_name),
            qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
            callback=self.on_get_shadow_accepted)

        get_rejected_subscribed_future, _ = self._shadow_client.subscribe_to_get_shadow_rejected(
            request=iotshadow.GetShadowSubscriptionRequest(thing_name=self._thing_name),
            qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
            callback=self.on_get_shadow_rejected)  # omitted

        # Wait for subscriptions to succeed
        get_accepted_subscribed_future.result()
        get_rejected_subscribed_future.result()

        log.info("Subscribing to Delta events...")
        delta_subscribed_future, _ = self._shadow_client.subscribe_to_shadow_delta_updated_events(
            request=iotshadow.ShadowDeltaUpdatedSubscriptionRequest(
                thing_name=self._thing_name
            ),
            qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
            callback=self.on_shadow_delta_updated)

        # Wait for subscription to succeed
        delta_subscribed_future.result()

        # From here on out the rest runs asynchronously.

        # Issue request for shadow's current value.
        # The response will be received by the on_get_accepted() callback
        with self._lock:
            publish_get_future = self._shadow_client.publish_get_shadow(
                request=iotshadow.GetShadowRequest(
                    thing_name=self._thing_name,
                ),
                qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE
            )

        # Ensure that publish succeeds
        publish_get_future.result()

    def on_get_shadow_accepted(self, response: iotshadow.GetShadowResponse) -> None:
        log.info("Finished getting initial shadow value.")

        if response.state and response.state.delta:
            if not response.state.reported:
                response.state.reported = {}
            merged_state = self.merge_states(response.state.delta, response.state.desired)
            return self.set_desired(device_shadow_from_json(merged_state))

        if response.state and response.state.reported:
            return self.set_local(device_shadow_from_json(response.state.reported))

        self.set_desired(SHADOW_VALUE_DEFAULT)
        return

    def on_shadow_delta_updated(self, delta: iotshadow.ShadowDeltaUpdatedEvent) -> None:
        if delta.state:
            if delta.state is None:
                log.info("Delta reports that nothing is set. Setting defaults...")
                self.set_desired(SHADOW_VALUE_DEFAULT)
                return

            log.info("Delta reports that desired shadow is '{}'. Changing local shadow...".format(delta.state))
            self.set_desired(self.merge_states(delta.state, self.shadow_value))

        else:
            log.info("Delta did not report a change")

    @staticmethod
    def merge_states(delta: dict, reported: DeviceShadow):
        for key, value in delta.items():
            reported[key] = value

        return reported

    def set_local(self, value: DeviceShadow) -> None:
        with self._lock:
            self.shadow_value = value

    def set_desired(self, new_value: DeviceShadow) -> None:
        with self._lock:
            if self.shadow_value == new_value:
                log.debug("Local shadow is already '{}'.".format(new_value))
                return

            log.debug("Changing local shadow to '{}'.".format(new_value))
            self.shadow_value = new_value

            log.debug("Updating reported shadow  to '{}'...".format(new_value))
            request = iotshadow.UpdateShadowRequest(
                thing_name=self._thing_name,
                state=iotshadow.ShadowState(
                    desired=asdict(new_value),
                    reported=asdict(new_value),
                ),
            )

            self._shadow_client.publish_update_shadow(request, mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
```

Below you will find the log:

```
DEBUG:app.mqtt:Connecting to xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com with client ID '80d8bc54-971e-0e65-a537-37d14a3cb630'...
INFO:app.models:Subscribing to Get responses...
INFO:app.models:Subscribing to Delta events...
INFO:app.models:Finished getting initial shadow value.
DEBUG:app.models:Changed local shadow to 'DeviceShadow(score_threshold=0.7, minimum_distance=1503)'.
DEBUG:app.models:Updating reported shadow  to 'DeviceShadow(score_threshold=0.7, minimum_distance=1503)'...
INFO:app.models:Update request published.
DEBUG:app.models:Finished updating reported shadow to '{'score_threshold': 0.7, 'minimum_distance': 1503}'.
INFO:app.models:Delta reports that desired shadow is '{'minimum_distance': 15035}'. Changing local shadow...
Exception ignored in: <class 'TypeError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tom/.../lib/python3.9/site-packages/awscrt/mqtt.py", line 506, in callback_wrapper
    callback(topic=topic, payload=payload)
TypeError: callback_wrapper() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'dup', 'qos', and 'retain'
DEBUG:app.models:Finished updating reported shadow to '{'score_threshold': 0.7, 'minimum_distance': 1503}'.
```

As you can see the stacktrace is pretty short, is there a way to debug this better?
Any ideas to why it is giving me this particular error and maybe how to solve it?
All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure the problem lies within

```py
@staticmethod
def merge_states(delta: dict, reported: DeviceShadow):
   for key, value in delta.items():
      reported[key] = value
   return reported
```

where the `__setitem__` call on the `reported` argument raises a `TypeError` because the reported argument is a `DeviceShadow` dataclass object that doesn't support item assignment.

If you want to set fields of a dataclass where you have a string of the field name, you can use `setattr(reported, key, value)`.